# Select Top 10 Based on Total of Entire Data, Grouped by Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table that records client connections for an online radio station. I am trying to produce a view that will return the Top 10 countries, based on listening time over the whole period, but grouped by the day, and date.

To clarify, the Top 10 will be the Top 10 over the whole period, and not just for each day. For example, USA may be our Number 1 country over all time, but some days it might drop down to say 12, I still need the overall Top 10 countries to be listed on a daily basis.

In effect, this should produce a view where for each day, there will be the same ten countries, but with total listening hours.

I have created a view that returns all countries:

```
SELECT DATE( datetime_end ) , country_code, SUM( duration ) /3600
FROM icecast_logs
WHERE mount = 'live'
GROUP BY DATE( datetime_end ) , country_code
```

Comment: Hi, the DBMS is MySQL, in response to the reply below, this produced the following table:

DATE(datetime_end)
country_code
SUM(duration)/3600 Descending

2015-07-31 United States 246.1731
2015-07-26 Germany 140.1286
2015-08-02 Germany 111.4447
2015-08-04 Germany 101.3333
2015-07-26 United States 100.9336
2015-07-30 United States 92.6492
2015-07-28 United States 92.5203
2015-07-27 Germany 91.3483
2015-07-30 Germany 90.6178
2015-08-03 United States 85.5922

I need ten results for every day, that shows the listening hours for the general Top ten countries

Comment: I tried this

SELECT DATE( datetime_end ) , country_code, SUM( duration ) /3600
FROM icecast_logs
WHERE mount = 'live' AND country_code IN (SELECT country_code       FROM icecast_logs
WHERE mount = 'live'
GROUP BY country_code
ORDER BY sum(duration) DESC)
GROUP BY DATE( datetime_end ) , country_code

But got this error

 #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 1):

For MSSQL use `TOP`

```
SELECT TOP 10 DATE(datetime_end), country_code, SUM(duration)/3600
FROM icecast_logs
WHERE mount = 'live'
GROUP BY DATE(datetime_end), country_code
ORDER BY SUM(duration)/3600 DESC
```

For MySQL use `LIMIT`

```
SELECT DATE(datetime_end), country_code, SUM(duration)/3600
FROM icecast_logs
WHERE mount = 'live'
GROUP BY DATE(datetime_end), country_code
ORDER BY SUM(duration)/3600 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

For Oracle you would need to use `RANK` &`ROWNUM`

```
WITH  top_icecast_logs AS
(
    SELECT DATE(datetime_end) AS Dateend, country_code, SUM(duration)/3600 AS SumTotalAmount, 
    RANK () OVER (ORDER BY SUM (SumtotalAmount) DESC) AS tsum
    FROM icecast_logs
    GROUP BY DATE(datetime_end), country_code
)
SELECT    Dateend, country_code, SumTotalAmount
FROM      top_icecast_logs 
WHERE     tsum <= 2
ORDER BY  SumTotalAmount DESC;
```

Comment: And for ANSI SQL and newer Oracle versions you use FETCH FIRST.

Comment: @jarlh yes very true, feel free to edit my answer to include that

Comment: I can't comment on the others, but that MySQL solution don't look right

Comment: @Strawberry Im pretty certain this is correct for MySQL, lemme test

Comment: @Strawberry done a quick test in sqlfiddle `SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10` works as expected.

Comment: No doubt. But NOT if you want to get the top 10, grouped by date.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by using an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT DATE( datetime_end ) , icecast_logs.country_code, SUM( duration ) /3600 FROM icecast_logs
INNER JOIN
(SELECT country_code
FROM icecast_logs
WHERE mount =  'live'
GROUP BY country_code
ORDER BY SUM( duration ) DESC 
LIMIT 10) AS TopTen
ON icecast_logs.country_code = TopTen.country_code

WHERE mount =  'live'
GROUP BY DATE( datetime_end ) , icecast_logs.country_code
```

Answer (score 0):

It's come to my understanding that you need daily statistics for TOP 10 listeners (here: countries) of all time.

First, we take those 10 country codes that have highest `duration` value, then for each day we print those stats for every country from those 10.

Remember, that if you do not have 10 countries, CTE will fetch less than 10 rows. Also, if a certain country hasn't been listening in some days, it won't show up in your results. This can be handled by first generating dates and then joining your data to those dates to show up every country in every date with lets say `0` value in `duration_hrs`

This should give you expected result.

```
WITH top_ten_all_time AS (
SELECT
   country_code
FROM
   icecast_logs
WHERE
   mount = 'live'
GROUP BY country_code
ORDER BY SUM(duration) / 3600 DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT
   DATE(a.datetime_end) AS date_x,
   a.country_code,
   SUM(a.duration) / 3600 AS duration_hrs
FROM
   icecast_logs a
   INNER JOIN top_ten_all_time b USING (country_code)
WHERE
   mount = 'live'
GROUP BY DATE(a.datetime_end), a.country_code
ORDER BY date_x, country_code
```